# How do I stop XCode 4.2 from going into std header files when doing "Step Over" in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode4

It's an absolute pain right now, I'm trying to debug some C++ code (and XCode is horrible enough to debug with as it is), but when I use F6 to step through code, it always goes through what appears to be various STD libraries and headers.  I'm sure there's a setting somewhere that I can change to stop this behavior, but I absolutely cannot find it.

Comment: Question is: why do you step into such methods? You might want to step over those calls leading down to C++ library code, or step out of such a function. I don't think this can be disabled.

Comment: I'm sorry for using the colloquial expression "step through".  I'm actually trying to step OVER a line of code, and instead of going to the next line of code, it plops me into a header library.  Notice that in the title, I mention that I am using a "Step Over" command and instead of stepping over, it's got me in a standard library.

Comment: @Charles are you forced to use XCode? I understand that the compiler it ships with is ancient and buggy.

Comment: To follow up on Cubic, XCode 4.5.1 is the current version. Are you using 4.2 because you want to support iOS 4 (or older)? How about just switching to 4.5.1 for the debugging session?